# Slick carousel controls over content

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I've created a full-width carousel with jQuery slick.js (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I'm trying to find a way to place the controls over the content pane rather than below. I know there are other carousels that offer this (bootstrap, etc.) but we use slick in our company JS and I would like to stick with it if possible. Has anyone had luck with this in the past?

Comment: Welcome! please, share us your code tries to be able yo help you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sure, sorry. Let me write up a summary.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The controls live in a slick-dots `<ul>` underneath the carousel `<div>` container. The div has a bottom margin and the ul is absolutely positioned inside of that margin. I was able to solve my problem using CSS and jQuery by removing the margin on the div and changing the CSS bottom value for the dots to place them within the carousel. Works like a charm! Here's a vague example:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "#my-carousel > .slick-dots" ).css("bottom","0px");
    $( "#my-carousel" ).css("margin","0px");
});
```

CSS would also work, but this is part of a JSP template file and I didn't want to affect other potential carousels.